# Get Woocommerce product variations outside loop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to list product variations and prices for each variation outside of woocommerce templates.
Anyone can suggest how can I access that info?

I have tried to do something like this:

```
$tickets = new WC_Product( $product_id);
$variables = $tickets->get_available_variations();
```

But this doesnt work because it is outside of loop, it returns error.

Idealy I would like to get all variations like an array:

```
$vars = array(
 array('name' => 'My var name', 'price' => '123'),
 array('name' => 'My var name', 'price' => '123'),
);
```

Maybe even if this can be done on 'save_post' for every product to create new post_meta and save this for future use, which would then be available to get like:

```
$meta = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_my_variations' );
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 10):

To get product variations outside the loop, you need to create new instance of WC_Product_Variable class, here is an example:

```
$tickets = new WC_Product_Variable( $product_id);
$variables = $tickets->get_available_variations();
```

In this way you will have all needed info for the variations in  $variables array.

Comment: I tried this and am getting errors ... is there more code eg globalizing variables necessary?

Comment: What errors you receive? It work well on my side without additional code or globalizing variables.

Comment: This doesn't work. `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING`

Answer (score 5):

This the simplest solution to get product variables using product ID, outside of loop and woocommerce template

```
$args = array(
'post_type'     => 'product_variation',
'post_status'   => array( 'private', 'publish' ),
'numberposts'   => -1,
'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
'order'         => 'asc',
'post_parent'   => $product_id // $post->ID 
);
$variations = get_posts( $args ); 
echo "<pre>"; print_r($variations); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this doesn't give me desired data.
I have found my way around, I have created a new loop

Comment: @Bobz It would be helpful to other users if you actually posted your solution to this problem.

Comment: @indextwo as mentioned above 'I have created a new loop'.
You can also check this plugin: http://www.eggplantstudios.ca/woocommerce-product-variation-add-cart-grid/

Comment: @Bobz That's great *for you*, but doesn't help anyone else. *How* did you create a new loop? Where did you put it? Could you post the code that solved your issue? Please try to remember that SO is also for other users who can be helped by your question (and your solution!), so to simply say 'I solved it' and disappear isn't very helpful. Some context for that link would be helpful too: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there." - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer